# sqlite diff-script generator

Tags: sql, sqlite, diff

Given two sqlite databases A and B, is there a tool that can generate SQL commands that will convert A to B (or vice versa)? This must included insertions, deletions, and updates - and maybe also table alterations (though that's not important to me).

Possibly this tool is not even sqlite-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be what you are looking for?

[SQLite Compare](http://www.sqlitecompare.com/)

Not sure what you mean by

> Possibly this tool is not even
>   sqlite-specific.

But a Sql Server specific one is available too.

[SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_data_compare/index.htm)

Comment: Almost. GUI comparison is nice, but what I wanted is automatic script generation.

Comment: The link given here for SQLite Compare points to a domain parking page, as of 2011-02-10.

Answer (score 0):

[CompareData](http://www.zidsoft.com/) will let you visually compare two sqlite databases and/or sync them or generate a sql sync script. Free for comparing the data, requires license after 30-day evaluation period expires for sync/generate sql sync script

Comment: Functionality looks useful.  $400 for single user license though.

Answer (score 0):

try this [SQLite-Compare-Utility](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220018/SQLite-Compare-Utility)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently added such a feature to the Pro version of [KS DB Merge Tools for SQLite](https://ksdbmerge.tools/for-sqlite). In the [Batch data diff](https://ksdbmerge.tools/docs/for-sqlite/tabs-batch-data-diff.html) such script can be generated with a few clicks.

Few other things relevant for this thread:

- Alter table scripts can be generated, but only as a separate action, there is no single button that would produce script both for schema and data changes. Batch data diff has a flag indicating that the table has schema changes to let you know that you probably need to prepare an alter table script.
- Currently it is GUI only, no command line. Full list of features in the windows app and free web app with basic diff features which works on mac and linux as well
- The order of statements respects foreign keys: for example for the tables pair of Parent and Child: INSERT and UPDATE statements are generated firstly for Parent and then for Child (to avoid insert of missing ParentID), DELETE statements have reversed order to avoid potential foreign key violation on trying to remove Parent before Child